# Wordpress showing page name instead of blog posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently working on my first Wordpress theme and I've a problem:

I want to have my last 3 posts on every site. Everything works fine on my home page, but when I go to another page it just shows the page name and the "Read more..." tag after it.

The code I use is:

```
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <div class="article-preview">
    <p>» <?php the_time('l, j. F Y')?></p>
    <b><?php the_title(); ?></b>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" style="color:white"> Mehr...</a>
    <hr style="margin-top:5px" />

  </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For displaying posts on other pages, you have to display custom query before while loop.

Here is the updated code of your code:

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type'=>'post', 'posts_per_page=3' ); ?>

// Start our WP Query
<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
  <div class="article-preview">
    <p>» <?php the_time('l, j. F Y')?></p>
    <b><?php the_title(); ?></b>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" style="color:white"> Mehr...</a>
    <hr style="margin-top:5px" />

  </div>
<?php endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

May be this would be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly!